# how to sum up all time values on a given date?

Tags: sql-server, datetime, stored-procedures, sum

I have a stopwatch project in C#. I have to start recording time and store it in my database in a `Timespan` column. I also have a `Timestamp` column which records the date that the time was recorded.

Now I want to have a store procedure(or anything) to pass the program a date and I want my program to search the database and sum up ALL values in every corresponding `Timespan` columns on the given date. In other words If I give it a date I want my program to look up every `Timestamp` column cells and if there is one or more timestamp equal to the given date I want the program to go ahead and check all of their related "Timespan" columns and sum them up.

My code only works if there is only 1 timestamp value equal to the given date and it yells at me if there is two or more. this is my problem.
 this is the error I get with:

> Additional information: Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is
>   not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when
>   the subquery is used as an expression.
>   I know the reson of the following error I just dont know the solution

please dont just try to correct my code, suggest me a new way if you could.
thank you.

My sum store procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SumOnDateReport
    @QueryDate nvarchar(50)
AS
    DECLARE @total_sec INT
    DECLARE @HourTime INT
    DECLARE @MinTime INT
    DECLARE @SecTime INT

    SET @HourTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2)) 
                     FROM InfoTable 
                     WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @MinTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2)) 
                    FROM InfoTable 
                    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)
    SET @SecTime = (SELECT CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2)) 
                    FROM InfoTable 
                    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate)

    SET @total_sec = @HourTime * 3600 + @MinTime * 60 + @SecTime

    INSERT INTO InfoTable(TotalSecColumn) VALUES (null)

    UPDATE InfoTable 
    SET TotalSecColumn = @total_sec
    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate

    SELECT TotalSecColumn 
    FROM InfoTable
    WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

my table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[InfoTable] (
    [Id]               INT           IDENTITY (1, 1) NOT NULL,
    [TimeSpanColumn]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [TimeStampColumn]  DATETIME      NULL,
    [TimeStringColumn] NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    [TotalSecColumn]   NVARCHAR (50) NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
);
```

Comment: Did you set the date to a primary key?  Then you can only insert one value for each date.    Inserting a second date with the same primary key would give error (Use update if primary key is already in table).

Comment: Try wrapping those converts with a SUM(), but if you are in control of the whole process I would suggest recording the duration column in seconds from the start.

Comment: @jdweng - his error pertains trying to return multiple rows into a variable

Comment: @KeithL I want to try to learn if im able to do it with minutes and houres.

Comment: Did you read : "MY CODE ONLY WORKS IF THERE IS ONLY 1 TIMESTAMP VALUE EQUAL TO THE GIVEN DATE AND"

Comment: @jdweng I didnt get your answer. i added my table.

Comment: This appears to have nothing to do with C#...

Comment: The issue is that variables are scalar, meaning they can hold ONLY a single value. When you assign a variable to the result of a query that returns multiple rows it will crash. How can the query engine know **which** row you want. Your questions would be a LOT better if you didn't scream at people in all caps. And instead of stating that it "yells at you", provide the error message so others aren't guessing.

Comment: @SeanLange Youre right I will edit my question. I knew the problem thank you but whats the solution?

Comment: ID is a primary key.  Are you using a different ID for each write?

Comment: The solution here would be to not use variables. They really aren't needed. I would also suggest using appropriate datatypes. numbers should not be stored as varchar, dates as strings, and do you really need to add "Column" to the name of every column? Seems rather redundant.

Comment: @SeanLange thank you for your good advices but what should I use instead of variables. any hints?

Comment: @jdweng No Im not. Id is a primary key.

Comment: Just write an update statement, you don't need the variables. You had to use them to break apart your disastrous string for a date to debug. Just put all those kludged substrings in your update statement. For me the real issue is not this query but the overall schema of this table.

Comment: @SeanLange youre right could you suggest a better schema? Im runing out of time on my project :( I would appriate it if you could. but for now you are telling me to just put all those substrings inside the update statement beneath them and it works?

Comment: Is this a school project? If so then don't bother. Just do your update. But you definitely need to go back and look at the datatypes and naming conventions here.

Comment: @SeanLange yup it is. okay thank you. but please let me inform you here if it worked or not. would you check my question tommorow or somtime soon?

Comment: @SeanLange would you please do the update thing you said as an answer? cause im encountering some errors...

Comment: @SeanLange I did it but the error exits...

Comment: What did you do and what is the error?

Comment: What do you think Primary means?  Primary means the database can have only one key with the same value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Close.  An integer variable can only accept a single value.  To get the single value, you group  and sum on each of the sub selects:

CREATE PROCEDURE SumOnDateReport
    @QueryDate nvarchar(50)
AS
    DECLARE @total_sec INT
    DECLARE @HourTime INT
    DECLARE @MinTime INT
    DECLARE @SecTime INT

```
SET @HourTime = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 1, 2))) 
                 FROM InfoTable 
                 WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
                 GROUP BY TimeStampColumn) * 3600
SET @MinTime = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 3, 2))) 
                FROM InfoTable 
                WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
                GROUP BY TimeStampColumn) * 60
SET @SecTime = (SELECT SUM(CONVERT(INT, SUBSTRING(TimeStringColumn, 5, 2))) 
                FROM InfoTable 
                WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
                GROUP BY TimeStampColumn)
SET @total_sec = @HourTime + @MinTime  + @SecTime

INSERT INTO InfoTable(TotalSecColumn) VALUES (null)

UPDATE InfoTable 
SET TotalSecColumn = @total_sec
WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate

SELECT TotalSecColumn 
FROM InfoTable
WHERE TimeStampColumn = @QueryDate
```

Comment: just one question, whats the purpose of `sum` here in this code? the `group by` is doing the same job as `sum`. did you keep it for some reason or im right? I deleted sum and checked that program is working just fine with out it.